# Is it possible to style the arrow of JScrollPane or JScrollBar?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

Is it possible to style the arrow of JScrollPane or JScrollBar? I want to change height and change symbol of the arrow if possible

Comment: In theory yes, but you'll need to provide your own UI look and feel delegate

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you please guide me on that? Thank you!

Comment: The four top hits [from goggle](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swing+customise+jscrollbar&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) would be a good start, but I'd also have a look at [Skinning a scroll bar – Part 1](https://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/skinning-a-scroll-bar-part-1/)

Comment: sounds good. will work on that. Thank you!